# How can I recursively find and replace in the current git repository

Tags: dired, git, replace, find-dired

I am working inside a git-repo. Here I want to apply my search operation based on the root directory of the git repo that current buffer is open.

Here I do: `find-dired "~/my_project" ...` in order to replace all Python files.

```lisp
(defun my-find-files ()
  (interactive)
  (message "press t to toggle mark for all files found && Press Q for Query-Replace in Files...")
  (find-dired "~/my_project" "-name \\*.py ! -name flycheck_\\*.py ! -name __init__.py"))

(global-set-key (kbd "M-z") 'my-find-files)
```

Instead how can I set `"~/my_project"` folder path dynamically based on the current buffer's root git repo.

`git rev-parse --show-toplevel` returns the root of the git repository where the file lives. I was wondering would it be possible to pass its return value instead of `"~/my_project"`?

Related: [Using Emacs to recursively find and replace in text files not already open](https://stackoverflow.com/a/271136/2402577)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `(vc-git-root (buffer-file-name))` in place of "~/my_project". It walks up the tree until it finds the directory that contains the `.git` subdir and declares that to be the root of the repo.

Comment: Can we also check condition if there is no git-repo in the folder in order to prevent `Error running timer: (void-function vc-git-root)` message?

Comment: You should ask this in a separate question: nobody will see this comment otherwise :-) You can refer back to this question for context.

Comment: Please see: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/69097/18414 . PS I am sorry for askling too many questions

Comment: Don't worry about asking "too many" questions: just try to make each one a *good* question: crisp and clear statement of the problem, as much information as necessary (but no more: *long*, meandering questions will discourage most responders), things you tried that failed to resolve the problem, version information etc. are all good things to include. Plus the standard rules: one question per question and do not change the question after posting (except for corrections and adding detail) - in particular, never change the original question to ask a different one: ask a new question instead.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `project-find-regexp` (<kbd>C-x p g</kbd>), from `project.el`, to find the regexp you are looking for and in the resulting buffer you can hit <kbd>r</kbd> (`xref-query-replace-in-results`) to replace what you need.

If your Emacs version does not come with `project.el` already built-in, you can get it from ELPA: https://elpa.gnu.org/packages/project.html

Comment: Would it be possible to make change only on the Python files?

Comment: If you do `C-u C-x p g` you can pick the directory and the file name pattern.

Comment: Can I set it single time and could it make the pattern search based on that?

Comment: You can write your own wrapper around `project-find-regexp` for that, which calls it with the parameters you need.

Comment: `your own wrapper around project-find-regexp` // can you give a small example how can I write a wrapper to handle only Python files?

Answer (score 0):

- Install counsel (https://elpa.gnu.org/packages/counsel.html)
- `M-x counsel-git-grep`
- Press `C-c C-o` or `M-x ivy-occur` to export result to a buffer in `ivy-occur-grep-mode`
- Press `C-x C-q` or `M-x ivy-grep-change-to-wgrep-mode` to switch to `wgrep-mode` and make the buffer editable
- Edit the buffer and press `C-c C-c` or `M-x wgrep-finish-edit` to commit the changes of the buffer. Then corresponding files will be updated

I use counsel&ivy because it provides the integration of `wgrep-mode`. Other completion/filter frameworks (helm, eg) could do the same thing.

Or you could integrate `wgrep-mode` into your own grep command.

Here is an example I grep my "emacs.d" and export the result of the buffer in `wgrep-mode`,

[image]

The key technology is `wgrep-mode`. You can edit one text buffer and change multiple files in one shot. Many techniques could be applied the text buffer first. For example, if I don't want to touch `README.org`, I just delete the line containing `README.org`.