# How can I prevent ` running timer: (void-function vc-git-root)` error

Tags: dired, git, find-dired

> `vc-git-root` walks up the tree until it finds the directory that contains the `.git` subdir and declares that to be the root of the repo.

But if there is not `.git` folder in the root directory, `(vc-git-root (buffer-file-name))`  gives following error `Error running timer: (void-function vc-git-root)`.

How could I fix it?

config:

```lisp
(defun my-find-files ()
  (interactive)
  (message "press t to toggle mark for all files found && Press Q for Query-Replace in Files...")
  (find-dired (vc-git-root (buffer-file-name)) "-name \\*.py"))
```

Related:

- [How can I recursively find and replace in the current git repository](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/68890/18414)

Comment: Have you tried `condition-case`, testing for such an error? Or if you want to ignore all errors, `ignore-error`.

Comment: What timers do you have running? *What* are they running? Why is `vc-git-root` called from a timer? What does the error have to do with `my-find-files`? IN my experiment, if there is no `.git` file found, then `vc-git-root` returns `nil`.

Comment: @NickD I am not sure what timer is running on the background. I just have following function related to `vc-git-root` in my config file. And I forget to use `(require 'vc-git)`

Comment: You might want to find out: `(list-timers)` and maybe chase it down further. Or not ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But if there is not `.git` folder in the root directory ... `(void-function vc-git-root)`

That error means that the function hasn't been defined.

The problem is that you haven't loaded the `vc-git` library before trying to use one of its functions.  That was only working in other cases because when you *are* in a git directory, `vc` figures that out and loads the library for you.

```
(require 'vc-git)
```

Comment: But why does a *timer* complain?

Comment: I expect that some information is missing from the question.  I don't think that's the important part, though.