# How can I recursively find and replace text in case sensetive?

Tags: dired, query-replace, case-folding, find

I am using combination of following solutions in order to `find-and-replace matched` text in all Python files:

- [Using Emacs to recursively find and replace in text files not already open](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8016053/2402577)
- [How can I recursively find and replace in the current git repository](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/68879/18414)

I observe that when I want to replace capital words like "HELLO_WORLD" , it also replaces `hello_world` string as well.

```lisp
(setq case-fold-search nil)

(defun find-and-replace ()
  (interactive)
  (message "press t to toggle mark for all files found && Press Q for Query-Replace in Files...")
  (find-dired (vc-git-root (buffer-file-name)) "-name \\*.py -o ! -name flycheck_\\*.py ! -name __init__.py ! -name \".*\" ! -name build ! -path \\*/.eggs/\\*"))
```

`M-x find-and-replace` ; then  `t` to toggle marked/unmarked files (thus marking them all, since none were marked). Then I use `Q` to use `query-replace on the marked files`. And enter `HELLO_WORLD` to replace with `WORLD_HELLO`.

How can I fix `find-and-replace` to work in case-sensetive?

Comment: Did you try setting (or binding) `case-fold-search` to `nil`?

Comment: Sorry to add it into my question, I had already have `(setq case-fold-search nil)` in my init file

Comment: Don't be sorry. Thanks for specifying that in the question.

Comment: `(setq case-fold-search nil)` is wrong in the init file. You must use `(setq-default case-fold-search nil)` since `case-fold-search` is a buffer-local variable. The setting `(setq case-fold-search nil)` just affects the single buffer where the init file is evaluated.

Comment: @Tobias `(setq-default case-fold-search nil)` solved my probles, please feel free to make it and answer. In generat I always use `setq` instad of `setq-default` like `(setq message-log-max t)` in my init file. Should I use `setq-default`instead ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already mentioned in the comments the variable `case-fold-search` is buffer-local.

The following line in your init file sets this variable only for the buffer to `nil` where the init file is evaluated:

```el
(setq case-fold-search nil)
```

To change the default value that is valid in all buffers where `case-fold-search` is not explicitly set you need to set the default value of `case-fold-search`:

```el
(setq-default case-fold-search nil)
```

Comment: Sorry for the late command, can this only applied for the `find-and-replace` but during `I-search` ignore case sensetive search?